# Calculating MINIMUM value based on two SELECT statement in Single SQL FUNCTION (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-function

I am trying to create a single `SQL FUNCTION`, where if I input my "a_id". SQL should return me MINIMUM Cost based on 3 different c_id's. 
My Tables are as follow.

```
TB1 : A (a_id (pk),a_name,a_description,a_qh)
TB2:  AC (ac_id (pk),a_id(fk),c_id(fk),ac_cost)
TB3: C (c_id(pk),c_name)
```

As an Example: if I have below table and I input a_id of 1 then SQL should be able to find all c_id associated with a_id of 1. Then based on that SQL should be able to calculate minimum value based on cost. For below example of a_id =1 SQL should return me c_id of 1 since it is with lowest cost of 150 out of 150,155, and 160 :

```
 a_id    a_description         c_id   Cost
    1   RS                      1   150.0000
    2   BS                      1   145.0000
    3   GS                      1   130.0000
    1   RS                      2   155.0000
    14  GH                      2   120.0000
    1   RS                      3   160.0000
    14  GH                      3   125.0000
```

I have created two `SELECT` statements achieve this:

Statement1:

```
SELECT 
    c_id, Cost, a_id 
FROM
    AC 
WHERE
    a_ID = 1);    -- This code returns all c_id associated with one  a_id
```

Statement 2:

```
SELECT
    MIN(AC.cost), c_id, a_ID
FROM
    AC
WHERE
    a_ID = 1
GROUP BY 
    c_id, a_ID
HAVING 
    MIN(AC.COST) <= (SELECT MIN(AC.COST) FROM AC)   -- This code calculates minimum cost based on 3 different c_id. AS 1 a_id can be sell be 3 different c_id
```

My dilemma is: how should I use above two `SELECT` statements in single function to achieve the lowest ac.Cost?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using, and what's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry.. I am using SQL server 2014. I have updated my question to reflect my PK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need other tables based on what im seeing, just AC. Here is a  rank query

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         *, 
         rank() over (partition by a_id order by cost asc) as cost_rank 
     from 
         AC) a 
where 
    cost_rank = 1 and a_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! What could be the reason of my second select statement not displaying c_id when I input a_id =1, but it shows c_id =2 when I input a_id=14. I have updated my SECOND SELECT statement.

Comment: Change the subquery in the second select to `<= (SELECT MIN(AC.COST) FROM AC WHERE a_ID = 1)`.  Or wrap the whole second select in two paranthesis and select from it and add a `WHERE a_ID =1` clause at the end then.  don't understand why you don't just use the ranking function though. Please mark the answer correct though

Comment: Thank for help. I started reading about RANK but I have never used it before. But sounds like it's good approach. Thanks again!